# In non-DMA scenario, does a storage device/disk content go to CPU registers first and then to main memory during a disk read?

Tags: io, cpu, device-driver, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

I am learning computer organization but struggling with the following concept. In non-DMA scenarios, do all disk reads follow the following sequence to get into main memory:

> Disk storage surface -> Disk registers -> CPU registers -> Main memory

Similarly for writes, is the sequence:

> Main memory -> CPU registers -> Disk registers -> Disk storage surface

(I know that in a DMA scenario, the CPU only initiates the transfer after which the content of the disks are transferred directly to main memory).

**If yes, before DMA came, was the above sequence a serious bottleneck as overall CPU registers' capacity is much less compared to main memory and storage disk? Or it is so fast that a human user won't notice in non-DMA modes?**

PS: Please bear with my rudimentary terminology, but I hope I conveyed what I want to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is on-topic for SO (seems like it belongs more on [cs.se],) but, yeah, that's generally how it works for non-DMA I/O operations. Non-DMA disk reads are quite rare, though.

Comment: @reirab So even if a disk file is to be memory-mapped, does it follow the above sequence and go through the CPU registers before entering the main memory?

Comment: In almost all cases, disk operations use DMA, so, no, that's unlikely. That would be horribly inefficient. Again, though, this question will likely be closed as off-topic here and should probably be posed in [cs.se] instead. SO is specifically for programming questions, not computer organization/architecture. You might also want to search [cs.se] first as it seems likely that this has been answered before there.

Comment: @reirab Please look into the edit to my question (in bold) and share your views so that my remaining confusion would be clear.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your answer. That nailed it for me.

Comment: converted it to a real answer then, since apparently that was sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you describe is what happened in the bad old days with [programmed-I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input/output) instead of DMA.

For example, IDE disk-controller hardware used to be less well standardized, so the Linux drivers defaulted to programmed I/O (i.e. a copy loop using [x86 `IN` instructions](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IN.html), since ATA predated memory-mapped I/O registers being common).  For decent performance, you had to manually enable DMA in your boot scripts.

But before doing that, check by manually enabling DMA it didn't lead to lockups, or *far* worse cause data corruption.

---

re: memory-mapped file:  nothing to do with how the data gets from disk into the pagecache (or vice versa).  mmap() just means your process's address space includes a shared mapping of the same pages that the OS is using to cache the file's contents.